# css background image shows infront of my other code

Tags: html, css

My background Image keeps showing up in front of everything. Of course I just want it to be the background...

I have tried setting a background image in my HTML file as well as my CSS file. Both are in front of my text and navbar.

`<img src="img/homepage.jpg" id="bg" alt="oops">`

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root{
    --bg-color: #D8D8D8;
}

body {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
color: #000;
font-family: 'Maitree', serif;
}
#bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%; 
}
```

I want my picture to be as a background.

Comment: Can you share a little more of your html please? If you want a background image, then you should set it in your css using `background-image` rather than by using an `<img />` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two option:

1. You can try to use the z-index (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)
2. You can use background image property in css, and put your image in this.https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

If you want more help, please paste some more code. Where is your image?

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck, css has just the thing you need, with the `background-image` property. You choose the element that you want to have a background and then set the image using css.

If you wanted it to be behind your entire `body` then you could try:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('img/homepage.jpg'); // make sure this path is relative
  background-size: cover; // cover is a good option here, but you might want something else
}
```

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background as you can do a number of things with the background, including position it, change the size, repeat it, and more.

Answer (score 0):

add this property `background-image: url("your image url");` to the body element (on css file), check the following link it will help you:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp